# What methods are there you inspect extremely large arrays in visual studio?

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am trying to debug code that works with byte arrays of extremely large sizes (7 million or so bytes), but the built in functionality of VS is insufficient, Array Visualizer cannot handle such sizes, and you cannot write your own custom debugging visualizers to work with arrays.  Is there an easy way to visualize or inspect regions of the array from within visual studio so I do not have to write the array to file and inspect it with a hex editor?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just write a property the returns the regions of the array you want and hover over that in the debugger to inspect it?

Comment: I would still like something where I could look at large ranges because the debugger's scrolling is not very fast... although I guess I could break it up into sizes that are still manageable by Array Visulaizer.. I suppose that will have to do

Comment: Very unclear what language this question is asking about, it matters.  Assuming C#, you can use the Immediate window to create an object.  For example `IEnumerable<int> view = Enumerable.Skip<int>(arr, 42).Take<int>(10);`  to select 10 elements of an array of integers, starting at index 42.  You can then put "view" in the Quick Watch window and look at the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging native languages you can use the following:

You can use the syntax (array + offset),  to watch a particular range of  elements starting at the offset position (of course, array here is your actual object). If you want to watch the entire array, you can simply say array, count.

[image]

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/469416/More-Visual-Studio-Debugging-Tips-for-Native-De